# ELGG and CAS integration

Tags: php, single-sign-on, social-networking

How to do a POC on SSO and Social Networking tool integration, and I had been provided with SSO and Social Networking tools. 
They are [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas/about-cas) and [ELGG](https://elgg.org/index.php).

I have an inner feeling that CAS should not be integrated with Social Networking Tool. I need to substantiate it.

Are CAS and ELGG integration right choices or not?